# PHP Bit shift on Windows7

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I have a laptop running Windows7 and if I right-click on "Computer" on the desktop and select properties I can see that "System type" is "64-bit Operating system" If I run PHP_INT_MAX as a watch in PHPStorm it gives me 2147483647, why? Does this indicate that PHPStorm is running as 32 bit or is PHP running in 32 bit mode? If I do php --version I can see that I am running PHP 5.4.7

My actual problem is that I am trying to do **$result = $var << 5** and $var was 318 497 757 before I got to this line of code. The $result after this line is 1601993632 but should be 10191928224 (if my math is correct)

What is going wrong and where? I have no idea what is wrong or where? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

By default, **all** public PHP builds from [windows.php.net](http://windows.php.net/download/) website are **32 bit**. From your description it sounds like you do have 32-bit one.

If you want 64-bit PHP then you need to find (or compile it yourself) and use 64-bit PHP build.

---

**How to check what xx-bit PHP you are using**

Check output of `phpinfo()` function (or just `php -i` from command line). Look for **Architecture** row on the top. 64-bit will have `x64` while 32-bit will have `x86`.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Any help on doing that on a Windows 7 machine?

Comment: Help doing what? Compiling -- sorry, never did this myself on windows (only on Linux, few years ago). As for downloading already compiled build -- just google it. I know that **WAMP server** has x64 bit option. Another choice is **[this site](http://www.anindya.com/tag/64-bit/)**

Comment: Found that one and am trying my best to get it working. I had XAMPP but looks like I am going to fall back to installing WAMP?

Comment: I'm running most of the websites on Windows platform (because of MS SQL Server as database engine) and using IIS 7.x as a webserver. It works fine with both x32 and x64 PHP (I've only tried x64, as some extensions are 32-bit only). As to XAMPP/WAMP -- I think you need 64-bit Apache in order to run 64-bit PHP. If XAMPP has it then I do not see any reason to move to WAMP. Alternatively -- do not use any bundle but install all components separately (I think 64-bit Apache should be available as separate installation).

Comment: Thanks, I have removed XAMPP and loaded WAMP - the download for WAMP states that it is a 64bit. How can I confirm that the PHP on WAMP is actually 64 bit?

Comment: I would suggest checking output of **phpinfo()** (or just `php.exe -i`) -- look at **Architecture** row on the top. 64-bit will have `x64` while 32-bit will have `x86`. Also check the WAMP settings as well -- it may come with both 32 and 64 bit so you may need to activate (and configure) correct one.

Comment: Ok, this is now driving me insane. phpInfo states: Architecture  x64 but still the problem persists? Where can I tell WAMP to run in 64 bit?

Comment: Also: check this notice: *"Don't right shift for more than 32 bits on 32 bits systems. Don't left shift in case it results to number longer than 32 bits. Use functions from the gmp extension for bitwise manipulation on numbers beyond PHP_INT_MAX."* from http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php